# Куда сдвигать объект-танк, если есть колизия?

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

У меня есть танк, который должен при столкновении со стенкой должен отодвигаться назад, желательно при помощи `collidepoint()`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот условие с помощью которого мы ловим колизию:

```py
collideblue = blue_tank.tank_object.collidepoint(xwall, ywall)
if collideblue:
   pass
```

Comment: Почему бы танк не сдвигать по вектору, обратного тому, по которому танк движется? Если танк пересекается со стеной, но единицу времени назад ещё не был, значит вполне можно придать ему перемещение (-v)*(delta t) - где v это вектор его скорости, а delta t - временная разница между кадрами.

Comment: А как найти разницу между кадрами если кадры постоянно обновляются?

Comment: Я не знаю, как именно работают используемые вами библиотеки. Также не позиционирую себя как профи в сфере игростроя — однако могу что-то предложить, а вы, на своё усмотрение, можете рассмотреть предложенные идеи.

Comment: У вас ведь, скорее всего, в программе самый классический цикл обработки событий? Ввод, логика (в т. ч. физика), рендер — и так по кругу.

Comment: Обычно принято на каждой итерации этого цикла обновлять время, а также получать разницу с временем старта предыдущего цикла. К этой разнице и привязывать всю логику, в том числе физическую.

Comment: Это даёт очень много полезных в разработке гарантий. Вы всегда знаете: на любом железе, вне зависимости от скорости исполнения, ваш танк будет двигаться со строго определённой скоростью. Его передвижение привязано уже не к тактам, а ко времени.

Comment: Без привязки ко времени этих гарантий нет. Условный хромиум в фоне отъел хорошенько ресурсов, ноутбук слабый — и вот танк начинает двигаться медленно. Запустили на современнейшем железе — и вот он движется с какой-то совершенно неадекватной скоростью. Становится понятно: от производительности может зависеть рендер, но для физики это почти всегда просто непозволительно!

Comment: Ну и вот таким образом, привязка ко времени может помочь в том числе и с обработкой коллизий. Вот ваш физический код обнаружил столкновение, надо что-то делать. У вас есть вектор его движения в данный момент, есть позиция... А ещё дельта времени. Отлично! Пока рендер ещё не запущен, можно как раз сдвинуть танк на обратный по скорости вектор, умноженный на разницу со временем, когда коллизии ещё не было. И вот он стоит ровно там, где вы это ожидаете. А на экране красивая картинка без некрасивых коллизий.

Comment: Ещё с таким подходом вы можете гибко контролировать скорость течения физики в игре. Допустим, ввести какую-то константу, на которую будете делать или умножать дельту времени. Захотели замедлить или ускорить процессы — достаточно поменять одну константу в коде.